# Moving elements from an arraylist to another by input

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists and I want to move items from itemsList to pawnItemsList.

```
public static List<Items> pawnItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
public static List<Items> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
public static String[][] itemsAttributes = new String[][]
        {
                {"Color TV ", "113", },
                {"Microwave ", "322",},
                {"Computer ", "1564",},
                {"Stereo ","402"}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   /* rentOffice rent = new rentOffice();
    employmentOffice emplyment = new employmentOffice();
    budget budget = new budget();
    factory factory = new factory();
    */
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    System.out.println("\n-------- PAWN SHOP --------\n");
    System.out.println("1. Pawn");
    System.out.println("2. Buy");
    System.out.println("3. Exit");
    choice = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    if(choice == 1)
    {
       pawnItems();
    }

    if(choice == 2)
    {
        addItems();
        printItemsList();
        buyItems();
    }
  }
```

I have a method called buyItems where I can buy items and after that the item I bought has to be added to pawnItemsList and removed from itemsList.

```
 public static void buyItems()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    if(itemsList.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("\nWhich item do you want to buy?(type the index)\n");
        int choice = in.nextInt() - 1;
        in.nextLine();
        itemsList.remove(choice);
        pawnItemsList.add(itemsList.get(choice));
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        printItemsList();
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        printPawnItemsList();

        buyItems();
    }
}
```

My problem is: when I want to buy the Color TV (the item has index 0 but the input must be 1 because I put int choice = in.nextInt() - 1;), the Color TV is removed from the itemsList but in the pawnItemsList is added the Microwave. I try to put pawnItemsList.add(itemsList.get(choice - 1)); but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have already removed item in item list. Then you can't call again.
`itemsList.remove(choice);
        pawnItemsList.add(itemsList.get(choice));`

Comment: The question is not clear at first glance, maybe you could put the problem first and the explanations later, also a better title. This helps preventing downvotes.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? You asked a question, but you don't seem to comment or validate the answers at all, which is quite impolite.

Answer (score 0):

In `buyItems` method, you first remove the user-selected item.

```
itemsList.remove(choice);
```

After this, the state of the `ArrayList` changes. The elements in its array are re-ordered, and the element originally at `choice + 1` index (unless you removed the last item) is now at `choice` index.

To fix the problem, you either need to get it first, or you can use the fact `remove` method returns you the object that was removed, so you could write:

```
Items item = itemsList.remove(choice);
pawnItemsList.add(item);
```